# Speed of snake javascript game

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm trying to create a simple snake game in JavaScript, so far so good, I have a code that works but there is a behavior I would like to remove.

Following is my JavaScript code

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var W = canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
var H = canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
var width = 10;
var height = 10;
var direction="right";
var snake = {
    length: 5,
    array_length: [],

    draw: function () {
        ctx.clearRect(0,0,W,H);
        this.array_length.forEach(function (x) {
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
            ctx.fillRect(x.x, x.y, width, height);
        });
        this.update();
    },
    update: function () {
        var first = this.array_length[0];
        var first_x = first.x;
        var first_y = first.y;


        switch (direction) {

            case "right":
                first_x++;
                break;
            case "left":
                first_x-=10;
                break;
            case "up":
                first_y-=10;
                break;
            case "down":
                first_y+=10;
                break;

        }
        var lasat=this.array_length.pop();
       // lasat.x=first_x;
       //lasat.y=first_y;
        this.array_length.unshift({
            x: first_x,
            y: first_y
        });


    },
    update_direction: function (e) {

        var key = e.keyCode;

        if (key == "37" && direction != "right") direction = "left";
        else if (key == "38" && direction != "down")direction = "up";
        else if (key == "39" && direction != "left") direction = "right";
        else if (key == "40" && direction != "up")direction = "down";
       //alert(direction);
    }
};

for (var i = snake.length; i >= 0; i--) {
    snake.array_length.push({
        x: i * width,
        y: 0
    });
}
window.onkeydown=snake.update_direction;
function swag(){
window.requestAnimationFrame(swag);
    snake.draw();
}
swag()
```

The behavior is in `switch` statement, when I increment the this `first_x` or `first_y` by 1, they became too small due to rect overcovering themselves, but when I increment them by 10, the snake is going too fast, I would like the snake to be at full length (like as incrementing by 10) but much slower.

How can I fix it? [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Trolstover/zLvq9nnq/) is a demo (default direction is right = incremented by 1. Others are incremented by 10, check the difference in length and speed)

Comment: Have you considered wrapping your update function with setTimeout()?

Comment: yes  instead of invoking in in snake.draw directily y tried using setTimeout(function(){
           
        snake.update()}, 1000); with various intervals , but the result was the same

Comment: OK - how about wrapping it around your draw function - or down in swag() around snake.draw() ?

Comment: try something like this http://jsfiddle.net/maio/zLvq9nnq/1/

Answer (score 2):

Your scale (10x10) and your coordinates don't agree. Your positions end up looking like (1,1), (1,2), etc, but when you draw a 10x10 square in that location you get massive overlap.

Use context save, restore, and scale to fix this - or you can change your coordinate system.

Here's an example:

At the top, when you define your variables:

```
 var width = 1;
 var height = 1;
```

In your draw function:

```
ctx.clearRect(0,0,W,H);
ctx.save();
ctx.scale(10,10);
this.array_length.forEach(function (x) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
    ctx.fillRect(x.x, x.y, width, height);
});
ctx.restore();
this.update();
```

I got the fiddle you provided working using that.
Cheers!

EDIT:

After a bit of mucking around with it, I got it mostly working by having each element in the chain have it's own direction, and then moving the switch for movement into a foreach. Sadly, I refreshed the page on accident and lost the fiddle, but it wasn't much of a modification.

Basically, the reason why they're overlapping is because each cell isn't moving - you're "leapfrogging" the tail to keep it moving forward - so smooth movement means moving less than a full grid cell's worth, which causes overlap.

Removing that overlap means moving by a full grid cell each tick, which means moving extremely quickly. So, you need to move by less than a full grid cell each tick, *for each element in the array*

ALSO:

DO NOT use setTimeout() like the comment above suggested. Use requestAnimationFrame, and if you want to use a staggered update setup, only call your update if your time between updates exceeds some time delta.

Comment: yes indeed it works , but the efffect is the same as incrementing by 10 , as i mentioned in my post , in this case i would like to reduce the speed of the snake.

Comment: If you want to get more flexibility out of it, you're probably going to have to make a choice:

Either go with a stepped time function so that every 1/4 second or so a move happens, or

In order to get smooth movement, move each element in the chain towards the next element.

Comment: i am aware of the "chaining method" , but in every "snake logic" i found this method of pushing the new "head " element and removing tail element. So i would like to fix it with this method

Comment: why has nobody mentioned that the requestAnimationFrame sends a high resolution timer value? Use that value to slow down frame rate.

Comment: Slowing down frame rate works, but I avoided doing that because it makes the movement stuttered. If you want smooth movement, you HAVE to interpolate each individual link in the chain.

Comment: i just reread your comment. I am actually "chaining" = changing value of every element in array. Or are you talking about other chaining? If so , what chaining?

Answer (score 0):

Use the parameter being passed to swag:

```
var lasttime=0;
function swag(time){
    window.requestAnimationFrame(swag);
    if (time - lasttime > 200) {
        snake.draw();
        lasttime = time;
    }
}
window.requestAnimationFrame(swag);
```

I will say, I like vyross solution better. It will look better, but this is a more direct answer to your question.